# how can i add any custom post to add to cart in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cart

i am using a custom post type in my site and want to add this post in cart item. i tried this code but not succeeded. this code is rendered as an ajax call from a button.

```
function buy_now_process_event() {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
if ($_REQUEST) {
    $product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $price_pro = $_REQUEST['price'];
}

if (!empty($items)) {
    foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        echo "<b>" . $_product->post_title . '</b>  <br> Quantity: ' . $values['quantity'] . '<br>';
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'], '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: " . $price . "<br>";
    }
    echo $items['product_id'];
} else {

    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1);
}
exit();
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "not succeeded"? Has an error occurred? Please provide more detail.

Comment: i mean my custom post is  not added in cart ahich i want